# How do I play S.A.W. vs Rebels in Super Animal Royale?

Tags: nintendo-switch, super-animal-royale

I'm on switch and want to try this gamemode but I can't find it.  It's not listed with the other gamemodes (solos, duos, squads, bwoking dead).  Does it require season pass or something, or is it not on the switch version?  Or am I just missing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some rotating game modes are only available for a limited time, and are commonly referred to as [Limited Time Modes](https://animalroyale.fandom.com/wiki/Game_Modes#Limited_Time_Modes):

- Mystery Mode
- The Bwoking Dead
- S.A.W. vs Rebellion: Control Point Mode

So, if you can play Bwoking Dead it means you just have to wait for the next rotation.

Comment: Ah, I wondered about that but on the page specifically for S.A.W. vs Rebellion they didn't mention that it was a ltm game mode so I assumed it wasn't.  Thanks for the help =D